# Android client for SignalR

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I need support in SignalR for Android client. I am using following client [SignalR/Java-Client](https://github.com/SignalR/java-client) but unable to know where to start :) We are completed .net self host & working fine. But only problem with Android & iPhone. Can any one please guide me how to start the next steps for Android & iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

You don't give a lot of details, so it's hard to give a concrete answer, especially since your question is very broad to begin with. Nonetheless, you should have a look at the [official samples](https://github.com/SignalR/java-samples) for the Java client, to get you started. If you have implemented the server side yourselves, and know your Java, it should be pretty easy to figure out from the code provided in these samples. The Java client is, in my experience, very easy to use.

As for an iOS client, a Google search came up with [this library](https://github.com/DyKnow/SignalR-ObjC). I have never used it, and it looks like it's not getting a whole lot of support, but you could always give it a shot.

Comment: If you have Android sample can you please share with me. We already  completed asp.net server side and working very well.

Comment: We started using using [Official samples](https://github.com/SignalR/java-samples) but facing problem with negotiation. This mean problem with our Asp.net server or Android application